# How to loop through all pages in a API Rest response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, woocommerce

I'm working on a code that will retrive products from a WooCommerce store. The API is returning only 100 products, while the total count is up to 147. The API returns two pages, but I can't seem to be able to loop through those pages.

This is my code so far:

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string apiUrl = "https://thestore.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100";
            string apiUsr = "usertoken";
            string apiPwd = "passwordtoken";

            string urlRequest1 = apiUrl;
            HttpWebRequest requestWeb = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlRequest1);
            requestWeb.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            requestWeb.ContentType = "application/json";
            requestWeb.Accept = "application/json";
            requestWeb.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            requestWeb.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(apiUsr + ":" +apiPwd));
            requestWeb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            requestWeb.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse responseHttpWeb = (HttpWebResponse)requestWeb.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = responseHttpWeb.GetResponseStream();

            //JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RetrieveMultipleResponse>>(JsonStr);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Stream webResponse = responseHttpWeb.GetResponseStream();
                string lector = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var mQuery = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(lector);
                int contarObjetos = mQuery.Count();
                contarItems.Text = contarObjetos.ToString();

                

                if (contarObjetos == 0)
                {
                    enviado.Text = "No existen registros";
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    foreach (var item in mQuery)
                    {
                        enviado.Text += item.id + ": " + item.name + " - " + item.status + "<br/><hr/>";

                        foreach(var elemento in item.categories)
                        {
                            enviado2.Text += elemento.id + ": " + elemento.name + "<br/><hr/>"; 
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            enviado.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        
    }
```

I've tryed changing the Uri parameter "per_page" but anything above 100 will break into an error.

I can modify the Uri to add a "page" parameter, so it will bring page 1, page 2, etc.:

```
string apiUrl = "https://antonelly.com.co/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&page=2";
```

But how can I get the number of pages from the api's headers and dynamically asign it to a loop?

This are the headers I see on Postman:

[image]

So i guess that if i can access that header and asign it to an object and increase on every loop, I will achieve what I'm looking for.

I've been going through WooCommerce's API documentation at https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#list-all-products but there's no info on how to do this, and in the JSON's response there is no object giving back the number of pages returned.

Any help will be huge for me!

Comment: Have you tried `responseHttpWeb.Headers`? For example: `string numPages = responseHttpWeb.Headers["X-WP-TotalPages"]; int numPages2; if (int.TryParse(numPages, out numPages2)) { // Success! }` If it gives you the number of pages, I can write some rows of code for extracting the other pages.

Comment: Yes! It brings back the number of pages (2 in this case) Thanks for that. But now, how can I loop trough those pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string apiUrl = "https://thestore.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100";
        string apiUsr = "usertoken";
        string apiPwd = "passwordtoken";

        int page = 1;
        int totalPages = 0;
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            string urlRequest = page == 1 ? apiUrl : apiUrl + $"&page={page}";

            HttpWebRequest requestWeb = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlRequest);

            requestWeb.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            requestWeb.ContentType = "application/json";
            requestWeb.Accept = "application/json";
            requestWeb.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            requestWeb.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(apiUsr + ":" + apiPwd));
            requestWeb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            requestWeb.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse responseHttpWeb = (HttpWebResponse)requestWeb.GetResponse();

            string totalPages2 = responseHttpWeb.Headers["X-WP-TotalPages"];

            // We don't really need to check for success. On failure it will write 0 and
            // will break the cycle
            int.TryParse(totalPages2, out totalPages);

            using (var stream = responseHttpWeb.GetResponseStream())
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var ser = new JsonSerializer();

                var items = ser.Deserialize<List<Root>>(jr);

                if (items.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (page == 1)
                    {
                        enviado.Text = "No existen registros";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    count += items.Count;

                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        enviado.Text += item.id + ": " + item.name + " - " + item.status + "<br/><hr/>";

                        foreach (var elemento in item.categories)
                        {
                            enviado2.Text += elemento.id + ": " + elemento.name + "<br/><hr/>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            page++;
        } while (page <= totalPages);

        contarItems.Text = count.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        enviado.Text = ex.ToString();
        contarItems.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The number of pages is in a header. You can access response headers from `responseHttpWeb.Headers["X-WP-TotalPages"]`. Then you have to parse the number. You can put the entire codeblock that makes requestes in a `do`-`while` cycle and check the page number (`page`) vs the total number of pages (`totalPages`). We recalc every "round" of `while` the `totalPages` but it isn't a problem.

Note that these paginated queries can suffer from contemporary changes to the database. If someone inserts/remove a product while you are paginating the responses, you could have the same item multiple times (if it was at the end of page 1 and is moved to page 2 while you are downloading the pages) or you could lose an item (if an item is removed somewhere and everything scrolls up), so you shouldn't consider what you obtain from webmethods like this to be "perfect".